# Handling multiple notification in android

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have an application which generates notification when a particular event that user entered on app occurs.Now for example user entered 7 events and he is not clicking on notifications then notification bar will became full. I don't want that. I want to show just one icon of notification but all 7 notifications. Just like `whatsapp` where only 1 notification icon is shown.

Comment: Create a custom layout for notification and have same notification builder id and update view for every new notification!

Comment: Create a unique NOTIFICATION_ID and used it for all Notification. If previous notification already exists then just update the UI of previous notification.

Comment: @user2163887 Thanks it is making sense to  me more but  An Example would be very nice.

Comment: Please refer to following http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm. May be it would help you.

Answer (score 5):

I guess what you are looking at is "Stacking" of Notifications.

There are couple of significant APIs here.
 1. `setGroup()` : This sets the notification to be part of a group of notifications sharing the same key.
 2.`setGroupSummary()`: Set this notification to be the group summary for a group of notifications.

Also, we Need to have same notification builder id. Below are my declarayions in class:

```
final static String GROUP_KEY_EMAILS = "group_key_emails";
int UNIQUE_NOTIFICATION_ID=422;
```

And Sample code to post notification:

```
Notification summaryNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)        
        .setContentTitle("2 new messages")        
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)                   
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()                
        .addLine("Notification 1   First line of info")                
        .addLine("otification 2   Second line of info")  
        .addLine("otification 3   Second line of info")
        .setBigContentTitle("3 new messages")                
        .setSummaryText("yourid@gmail.com"))        
        .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_EMAILS)        
        .setGroupSummary(true)        
        .build();


        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =  NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(UNIQUE_NOTIFICATION_ID, summaryNotification);
```

This will show the UI As below:

[image]